Use artifactory as cache input for Docker build
I am able to build docker image and push them to artifactory for later use using these commands:
docker build -t my-artifact.my-artifactory-server/path-into-artifact:my-tag local-Dockerfile-folder
docker push my-artifact.my-artifactory-server/path-into-artifact:my-tag

The thing is, I would like to make the Docker build command to use artifactory as cache to build the image faster.
I tried with --cache-from option. Not sure it is the right option.
